# Does iOS app "Application Support" folder persist across app update?

Tags: ios, file-management

Inside an iOS app, there is `/Library/Application Support` folder (accessed with `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`). I save user downloaded contents there. The contents are like patch files to add new images and data for my app. I want it to persist across app updates. I **DO NOT** want to backup those files.

I'm not sure which to use from this huge list from `NSPathUtilities.h`. My candidates are `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` and `NSDownloadsDirectory`. Can't find if they would be persisted differently or not.

```
    NSApplicationDirectory = 1,             // supported applications (Applications)
    NSDemoApplicationDirectory,             // unsupported applications, demonstration versions (Demos)
    NSDeveloperApplicationDirectory,        // developer applications (Developer/Applications). DEPRECATED - there is no one single Developer directory.
    NSAdminApplicationDirectory,            // system and network administration applications (Administration)
    NSLibraryDirectory,                     // various documentation, support, and configuration files, resources (Library)
    NSDeveloperDirectory,                   // developer resources (Developer) DEPRECATED - there is no one single Developer directory.
    NSUserDirectory,                        // user home directories (Users)
    NSDocumentationDirectory,               // documentation (Documentation)
    NSDocumentDirectory,                    // documents (Documents)
    NSCoreServiceDirectory,                 // location of CoreServices directory (System/Library/CoreServices)
    NSAutosavedInformationDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 11,   // location of autosaved documents (Documents/Autosaved)
    NSDesktopDirectory = 12,                // location of user's desktop
    NSCachesDirectory = 13,                 // location of discardable cache files (Library/Caches)
    NSApplicationSupportDirectory = 14,     // location of application support files (plug-ins, etc) (Library/Application Support)
    NSDownloadsDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0) = 15,              // location of the user's "Downloads" directory
    NSInputMethodsDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 16,           // input methods (Library/Input Methods)
    NSMoviesDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 17,                 // location of user's Movies directory (~/Movies)
    NSMusicDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 18,                  // location of user's Music directory (~/Music)
    NSPicturesDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 19,               // location of user's Pictures directory (~/Pictures)
    NSPrinterDescriptionDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 20,     // location of system's PPDs directory (Library/Printers/PPDs)
    NSSharedPublicDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 21,           // location of user's Public sharing directory (~/Public)
    NSPreferencePanesDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 22,        // location of the PreferencePanes directory for use with System Preferences (Library/PreferencePanes)
    NSApplicationScriptsDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_8, NA) = 23,      // location of the user scripts folder for the calling application (~/Library/Application Scripts/code-signing-id)
    NSItemReplacementDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 99,       // For use with NSFileManager's URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:
    NSAllApplicationsDirectory = 100,       // all directories where applications can occur
    NSAllLibrariesDirectory = 101,          // all directories where resources can occur
    NSTrashDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_8, NA) = 102                   // location of Trash directory
```

Comment: Why don't you use: `NSDocumentDirectory` or `NSUserDirectory`?

Comment: @Raptor Because I don't want to include those files in device backup.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13) files placed with the `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` will indeed be persisted during backups, but it's possible to set resource values to exclude them from the backup process on a case-by-case basis.

> Remember that files in `Documents/` and `Application Support/` are backed up by default. You can exclude files from the backup by calling `-[NSURL setResourceValue:forKey:error:]` using the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` key. Any file that can be re-created or downloaded must be excluded from the backup. This is particularly important for large media files. If your application downloads video or audio files, make sure they are not included in the backup.